# How to download and save large file from window azure?

Tags: download, azure-storage

I have a large file on window azure and I want to download and save it on my disk. The maximum time for each link on window azure is 60 minutes. If I dowload directly base on link, maybe it isn't enough time. How to download it?

Comment: http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloud-storage-studio/introduction i have used this for uploading large files you can try it

Answer (score 1):

Nathan, your question isn't very clear, but I suspect you are referring to the time allowed for a Shared Access Signature, and being concerned that the client might not download the file within the time allowed?

There are 2 scenarios here:

1. Once a storage transaction (ie. download file) which uses a SAS
   begins, then the transfer will be able to continue past the
   expiration of the SAS.  It is only new requests which are
   authenticated using the SAS and which will fail if they are
   attempted past the expiration time on the SAS.
2. If the client has to resume the download (or is downloading in
   blocks), then the client has to be smart enough to detect the failed
   authentication after the SAS expires and then re-request a new SAS
   from the issuer.

Answer (score 0):

try using a download accelerator like flashgot or something similar ...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to download the file in pieces and reassemble it once you have the pieces. There are a couple of ways to do that.

1. If the blob was uploaded in multiple blocks, then you could download each block individually. This is supported directly in the client libraries, so if you can do this it's probably easier. You can also download the blocks in parallel to reduce the total time it takes to download.
2. You could use HTTP Range headers to get certain byte ranges. I don't believe this is supported in the clients, so you'd probably have to code it yourself. But it will work even if the blob was not uploaded in blocks. I think this could also be done in parallel, but I'm not sure.